# No build.gradle is created when importing an existing Java project with Gradle in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, buildship

I have Java projects in Eclipse Mars. I have Buildship 1.0.21 and Gradle 3.1. In Eclipse I right click a project and press `Import > Gradle Project` and go through the wizard. When I'm done my project has its Gradle nature `G` symbol but no `build.gradle`, gradle wrapper folder or anything else gradle related (my other "real" projects have `gradlew` and `gradle.bat` files too).

Why does this happen and how to I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welll, actually you don't have to have a `build.gradle` file or the Gradle wrapper to have a valid Gradle project. I guess eclipse is just recording in its metadata that this is a Gradle project but does not add any build files for you. But this is just a guess, as I use IntelliJ IDEA and not Eclipse for very good reasons.

Try going on the commandline to your project and execute `/path/to/gradle init` and Gradle will add the wrapper files and a basic `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle`. You can even give the init task a parameter to tell which kind of project this is, depending on this the create files may differ slightly. Or you can only do `/path/to/gradle wrapper` to just add the Gradle wrapper but not auto-create build files. Afair you can even tell the wrapper or init task which Gradle version the wrapper should use, in case it should be a different version from the gradle you are calling to create the wrapper files.